# Java's MessageDigest SHA1-algorithm returns different result than SHA1-function of php

Tags: java, php, sha1

I have a SQL table with usernames and passwords. The passwords are encoded using MessageDigest's digest() method. If I encode a password - let's say "abcdef12" - with MessageDigest's digest() method and then convert it to hexadecimal values, the String is different than if I do the same using PHP's SHA1-method. I'd expect these values to be exactly the same though.

Code that is used to encode the passwords:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] passbyte;
passbyte = "abcdef12".getBytes("UTF-8");
passbyte = md.digest(passbyte);
```

The conversion of the String to hexadecimal is done using this method:

```
public static String convertStringToHex(String str) {

    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
    }

    return hex.toString();
}
```

Password: **abcdef12**

Here's the password as returned by a lot of SHA1-hash online generators and PHP SHA1()-function: **d253e3bd69ce1e7ce6074345fd5faa1a3c2e89ef**

Here's the password as encoded by MessageDigest: **d253e3bd69ce1e7ce674345fd5faa1a3c2e2030ef**

Am I forgetting something?

Igor.

Edit: I've found someone with a similar problem: [C# SHA-1 vs. PHP SHA-1...Different Results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790232/c-sha-1-vs-php-sha-1-different-results) . The solution was to change encodings.. but I can't change encodings on the server-side since the passwords in that SQL-table are not created by my application.
I use client-side SHA1-encoding using a JavaScript SHA1-class (more precisely: a Google Web Toolkit-class). It works and encodes the string as expected, but apparently using ASCII characters?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the encodings. The output would be entirely different.

For starters, your function `convertStringToHex()` doesn't output leading zeros, that is, `07` becomes just `7`.

The rest (changing `89` to `2030`) is also likely to have something to do with that function. Try looking at the value of `passbyte` after `passbyte = md.digest(passbyte);`.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer solved my problem. I was failing at converting the byte-array to a hexadecimal string properly! I used the method from @stivlo and it worked great! I am going to mark this response as correct, though in this case I wish I could mark both given responses as the correct one! Thank you both!

Answer (score 6):

I have the same digest as PHP with my Java SHA-1 hashing function:

```
public static String computeSha1OfString(final String message) 
    throws UnsupportedOperationException, NullPointerException {
        try {
               return computeSha1OfByteArray(message.getBytes(("UTF-8")));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(ex);
        }
}

private static String computeSha1OfByteArray(final byte[] message)
    throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.update(message);
            byte[] res = md.digest();
            return toHexString(res);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(ex);
        }
}
```

I've added to my unit tests:

```
String sha1Hash = StringHelper.computeSha1OfString("abcdef12");
assertEquals("d253e3bd69ce1e7ce6074345fd5faa1a3c2e89ef", sha1Hash);
```

Full source code for the class is [on github](https://github.com/stivlo/obliquid-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/org/obliquid/helpers/StringHelper.java).

Comment: Indeed - your code produces the correct SHA1 (or rather: the same as SHA1 of php). However, I am writing an application that has to login into an existing database. That database is not created by myself (and neither is the password encryption). But **it uses the MessageDigest as written in my example** and thus running Base64.decode on that String returns a different result (the one specified in my example) rather than your correct result, which I also get using that JavaScript SHA1-class. Is there any way to compare them? I don't know how MessageDigest was returning that other result.

Answer (score 5):

Try this - it is working for me:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
md.update(original.getBytes());
byte[] digest = md.digest();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (byte b : digest) {
    sb.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
}
return sb.toString();
```

Regards,
Konki

Answer (score 3):

Or try this:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
md.update(clearPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
return new BigInteger(1 ,md.digest()).toString(16));
```

Cheers Roy

Comment: For starters, with the BigInteger doesn't output leading zeros, that is, 07 becomes just 7.