# php sha1 not equal java sha1

Tags: java, php, hash, sha1, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java’s MessageDigest SHA1-algorithm returns different result than SHA1-function of php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605217/javas-messagedigest-sha1-algorithm-returns-different-result-than-sha1-function)

what I use:

java:

```
public String sha1(String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

result:

```
java: System.out.println(sha1("foobar123dsadn23u1wdqqwdyxdasd"));
php:                echo sha1('foobar123dsadn23u1wdqqwdyxdasd');

php:  d8033103e9aaf67af13a4b45534b2d0f6d8dfded
java: d83313e9aaf67af13a4b45534b2df6d8dfded
```

Why not the same the two hash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because `Integer.toHexString` in Java does not print two digits if the number is less than 16. So, for example 8 becomes `8` instead of `08`.

You need to propertly format the numbers. This should do it:

```
hexString.append(String.format("%02X", 0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
```