# equivalent PHP sha1 in C#, with raw binary format and a length of 20

Tags: c#, php, sha1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# SHA-1 vs. PHP SHA-1…Different Results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790232/c-sharp-sha-1-vs-php-sha-1-different-results)

I am trying to find out what the PHP `sha1(string,true);` equivalent method is in C#. I tried searching a lot and also tried writing some code, but couldn't find any solution. Can anyone tell me how to get `sha1` in row binary format with a length of 20, like the PHP function: [SHA1 in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)?

In PHP:

```
sha1($sampletext, true);
```

In C#:

```
string sampletext= "text";
SHA1 hash = SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString);
byte[] hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextBytes);
```

Both return a different output.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This IDEOne test](http://ideone.com/L83lJ) seems to produce the same output as using UTF-8 encoding for the hash in C#:

```
string sampletext = "text";
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 hash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sampletext);
byte[] hashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextBytes);

foreach (byte b in hashBytes) {
    Console.Write(string.Format("{0:x2}", b));
}
```

This will be platform-specific depending on how the PHP handles it. It may even be ASCII from some of the documentation. It's all to do with character encoding.

Comment: Thank you Simon, Your Answer helped me, and also helped me to clear some doubts.