# PHP equivalent of .NET Code

Tags: php, .net, sha1

I am converting .net project to PHP . But unable to convert the following code:

```
public static string HashString(string value)
    {
        SHA1 hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

        UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();

        byte[] hashInBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(value));

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashInBytes);
    }
```

So far I have done this but result is not same:

```
function HashString($str) {
  return base64_encode(sha1($str));
}
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# SHA-1 vs. PHP SHA-1...Different Results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790232/c-sharp-sha-1-vs-php-sha-1-different-results)

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the difference is, PHP uses ASCII encoding for hash calculations.

In C#, you can replace `UTF8Encoding` with `ASCIIEncoding` in order to have same results.

Comment: I have a database filled with the encrypted password field,, and I want to use the same database, . Iam creating the project in PHP so its not useful for me to convert .net code.

Comment: Is there a way I can use utf8 encoding sha1 in php

Comment: password uses Unicode characters? that's weird. It's suggested to change the mechanism in C# instead.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

This is the final code which is equivalent to .net code:

```
function HashString($str) {
  return base64_encode(sha1($str,true));
}
```

I have added "true" with sha1 function.