# Converting C# Sha1 hash to PHP

Tags: c#, php, sha1

I'm trying to get a C# Sha1 hash in PHP. The C# code was handed to me, it appears to use ASCIIEncoding which from what I read is what PHP uses. Not sure what is wrong. Any tips are appreciated.

C# code:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
byte[] HashValue; 
SHA1Managed SHhash = new SHA1Managed();
hashValue = SHhash.ComputeHash(data);
foreach (byte b in hashValue)
{
    sha1string += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
}
return sha1string;
```

PHP Code:

```
return sha1(text);
```

The output:

```
C#  : 5f10f7410406cdab11f3c44fe8c634718eb68e98
PHP : bba18b9b35c440c25b8dcf2efb973d86ee1442e2
```

Comment: so what does `text` look like in php, v.s. what's in `data` in c#? even one single BIT different in any of the individual bytes will completely throw off the hash. e.g. maybe one's got a newline you didn't account for.

Comment: thats what i was thinking. I wanted to make sure that i was correct first. i'm waiting to hear back, the string I have contains a public email so I can't post it on here.

Comment: well, you can always test it with some other string. doesn't have to be your private data. if it's failing on one string, it'll probably fail similarly on any other string.

Comment: Most likely an encoding mismatch. PHP treats strings as sequences of bytes, but those can differ for seemingly identical strings depending on what encoding is used to save the script. For instance, `sha('é')` will produce two completely different hashes if saved as ISO-8859-1 (where é is `e9`) vs. UTF-8 (`c3a9`).

Comment: You can use a dummy email address. No need to use a real one but it is quite useful omho to know what `text` looks like.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790232/c-sharp-sha-1-vs-php-sha-1-different-results

Comment: The hash algorithms matched up, the data provided was incorrect.